# How to calculate the image dataset's mean and std for deep learning?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, image-processing

Which is correct? Suppose that the `image`'s size is (channels, height, width).

`means = np.zeros(3)
stds = np.zeros(3)
for image in dataset:
    image = image.reshape(channels, -1)
    means += image.mean(1)
    stds += image.std(1)
mean = means / len(dataset)
std = stds / len(dataset)`

`images = [image.reshape(channels, -1) for image in dataset]
images = np.concatenate(images, 1)
mean = images.mean(1)
std = images.std(1)`

I googled many times, I still do not find out that how to calculate imagenet's std and mean !

Comment: The second one is correct.

Comment: @JanKukacka Any paper supports it?